# uib-carousel two images in one slide from an array of images

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have an array of images.One image on 1 slide is working fine but,
I want to show two images on 1 slide 
This is my plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/2GRRijUJDzuHNnHbr2U2?p=preview

This is my markup for one image per slide

```
<uib-carousel active="active" interval="myInterval" no-wrap="noWrapSlides">
  <uib-slide ng-repeat="slide in slides track by slide.id" index="slide.id">
    <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}" style="margin:auto;">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h4>Slide {{slide.id}}</h4>
      <p>{{slide.text}}</p>
    </div>
  </uib-slide>
</uib-carousel>
```

Comment: Do you need to iterate over a list of *pair* of images or iterate over a list of images 2 by 2 ?

Comment: yes i need to iterate 2 images per slide and thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

If what you need is to iterate over pair of images you can do it like that :

http://plnkr.co/edit/URRvZUwohYOSsypVSd8I?p=preview

I changed the `addSlide` function:

```
  $scope.addSlide = function() {
    var newWidth = 600 + slides.length + 1;
    slides.push({
      image1: 'http://lorempixel.com/' + newWidth + '/300',
      image2: 'http://lorempixel.com/' + newWidth + '/300',
      text: ['Nice image','Awesome photograph','That is so cool','I love that'][slides.length % 4],
      id: currIndex++
    });
  };
```

And the `<uid-slide>` template

```
  <uib-slide ng-repeat="slide in slides track by slide.id" index="slide.id">
    <div>
      <img ng-src="{{slide.image1}}" style="width:50%;display:inline-block">
      <img ng-src="{{slide.image2}}" style="width:50%;display:inline-block">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h4>Slide {{slide.id}}</h4>
      <p>{{slide.text}}</p>
    </div>
  </uib-slide>
```